# If the Continuous image of a space is compact, does that mean the space is compact?

Tags: continuity, compactness

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $f(X)$ is compact. Is $X$ necessarily compact?

Is there an example to prove/disprove this?

Thank you.

Comment: If the condition is for *all* $f$ continuous $f(X)$ is compact, then is true (but trivial) that $X$ is compact.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla but in the two answers $f$ is continuous and $f(X)$ is compact but $X$ is not compact?

Comment: For *one* $f$ is much less than for *all* $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by `one` and `all`?

Comment: All = every. One =... one.

Comment: oh, so you mean if every function is continuous and compact on $X$ then $X$ is compact. Is that right?

Comment: If for every $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ continuous $f(X)$ is compact then $X$ is compact (proof: take $Y = X$, $f=$ identity).

Comment: @MrDi:  You should be able to find an example of a continuous map from $X$ to a compact space, regardless of what topological space $X$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let be $X$ any space and $f$ constant...

Comment: What if the image was not continuous, does that change anything?

Comment: @MrDi, if $f$ isn't continuous any topological question is irrelevant. The only restriction is cardinal(imege set)$\le$ cardinal($X$).

Answer (score 2):

The image of $(-1,1]$ by $x \to x^2$ is compact.